# Real root of a real equation2

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: If $ \alpha_n$ is a real root of equation $x^n=-x+1$ and
$ \alpha_{n+1}$ is a real root of equation $x^{n+1}=-x+1$ then show that 
$$0<\alpha_n <\alpha_{n+1}<1~(n\in \mathbb{N})$$

Answer (score 2):

We are given that $\alpha_n=1-\alpha_n^n$ or that $1-\alpha_n-\alpha_n^n=0$ Evaluating the $n+1$st function at $\alpha_n$ gives $1-\alpha_n-\alpha_n^{n+1}\gt 0$ and at $1$ it is $-1$ so by the intermediate value theorem there is a root in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

$(\alpha_n)^{n+1}+\alpha_n-1<(\alpha_n)^{n}+\alpha_n-1=0$ and $(1)^{n+1}+1-1=1>0$.
From the property of continuous function $x^{n+1}+x-1$, $\alpha_n<\alpha_{n+1}<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the function values at x=0 and x=1 shows that, whatever could be n >0, the root is between 0 and 1. Now, you could consider the problem as the intersection of the curves x^n and x^(n+1) with the line (1-x). Considering the slopes and the curvatures prove it.